# How to calculate value in puppet erb file

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

I'm new to puppet and realy need some help with it:

I have the following value im my application my_app.pp value:

```
akka_application_cluster_seed_nodes => '"akka.tcp://ActorSystem@host1:2551","akka.tcp://ActorSystem@host2:2551","akka.tcp://ActorSystem@host3:2551"'
```

Now in my erb file `min-nr-of-members` value should be calculated by getting the size of `akka_application_cluster_seed_nodes` array divide by 2 plus 1

```
 $min-nr-of-members = $akka_application_cluster_seed_nodes.size/2 +1
```

For example:

```
  auto-down-unreachable-after = <%= get_param('akka_cluster_auto_down_unreachable_after')%>

and something like this:
      <% $cluster= get_param('akka_cluster_auto_down_unreachable_after') %>
      <% $minNumOfNodes = ($cluster.size / 2)+1 %>

min-nr-of-members = <% $minNumOfNodes %>
```

Can you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'"akka.tcp://ActorSystem@host1:2551","akka.tcp://ActorSystem@host2:2551","akka.tcp://ActorSystem@host3:2551"'
```

is not an array in puppet. 
Use [split](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/function.html#split) function to create an array from it :

```
$array_nodes = split($akka_application_cluster_seed_nodes, ',')
```

Next use [size](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/stdlib#size) function from stdlib to calculate array size in puppet, and calculate desired value:

```
$array_size = size($array_nodes)
```

Then use it in your erb file:

```
min-nr-of-members = <%= Integer(@array_size) / 2 + 1 %>
```

Comment: Yes! Or all of it in Ruby. `<%= @akka_application_cluster_seed_nodes.split(',').length / 2 + 1 %>`.